# how to send data in post method from Javascript to nodejs server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, post, methods

I am sending some data from my `main.js` to node js

here is my node js code

#index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
var cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.post('/listUsers', function (req, res) {
  var t = (req.body.uuu);
console.log("C"+t);
})
var server = app.listen(8081, function () {
   var host = server.address().address
   var port = server.address().port
   console.log("Example app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)
})
```

and here is my `Javascript` code from where I am sending the data

```
usid();
function usid(med){
  var f = "my new name";
  var json_data = [];
  json_data.push(f);
  var uuu = JSON.stringify(json_data);
  $.ajax({
    crossDomain: true,
    url:"localhost:8081/listUsers",
    method:"POST",
    data:{med,uuu:uuu},
    success:function(data,status){
      console.log("send");
    }
  })
}
```

`Cannot GET /listUsers` this the error in my webpage

can you tell me what I am doing wrong here ??thanks

Comment: what jquery version? also try `url:"http://localhost:8081/listUsers",`

Comment: Query 2.2.4 which I have used

Comment: And even This `http://` also didn't worked